# Changes to App.exe.config file in between sessions not reflecting in the Application on target pc

Tags: c#, build, connection-string, app-config

I have been working on an app that connects to a datastore using type datasets.  When I build the app and run it on the development pc, it runs perfectly well.  However, when run on the target pc, it crashes giving this error message from Event Viewer:

```
Application: Gui.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionString, System.Data.OleDb.DataSourceWrapper ByRef)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionString, System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey, System.Object, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool, System.Data.Common.DbConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolGroup, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal ByRef)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(System.Data.DataSet, System.Data.DataTable[], Int32, Int32, System.String, System.Data.IDbCommand, System.Data.CommandBehavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(System.Data.DataTable[], Int32, Int32, System.Data.IDbCommand, System.Data.CommandBehavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(System.Data.DataTable)
   at DataGateway.FteHostDataSetTableAdapters.ActivityTableAdapter.Fill(ActivityDataTable)
   at DataGateway.FteHostData.FteHostDataManager.SetupTables()
   at DataGateway.FteHostData.FteHostDataManager..ctor()
   at DataGateway.FteHostData.FteHostDataManager.GetInstance()
   at DataGateway.SettingsMappers.DaoSettingsDataMapper..ctor()
   at Gui.Controllers.Controller..ctor()
   at Gui.Controllers.Controller.GetInstance()
   at Gui.App.App_Startup(System.Object, System.Windows.StartupEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Application.OnStartup(System.Windows.StartupEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at Gui.App.Main()
```

I think the error is coming from a the application not having the right connection string on the target pc.  I have therefore changed the connectionString to the location of the Access Database file on  the target PC.  However, the error persists.

While troubleshooting, I decided to introduce an error into the connectionString on the development, but to my surprise the application still runs.

Can anyone help to understand why this is happening? How can I solve the problem with the target pc.

Thanks.

Note: The Application has four DLLs.  One for the GUI is the startup application, one of the dlls is the DataGateway, which holds the properties that contain definitions for the connectionString.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to resolve this.  The GUI component was not able to use the DataGateway because the connectiontring was not defined in its config file, it was defined in the DataGateway Component, which is the datalayer of the app.  I am still not very clear why this works in development but not in deployment.

I moved the connnectionstring to the GUI component's config file and then everything works fine.